# Configure PHP to work with MSSQL by using SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to configure PHP to work with MSSQL database. I found some instructions on the internet, but I didn't succeed.
I'm using php 5.3, MS SQL 2008, server is Openserver 5.2.2, OS is Windows 8.1.

1. I installed MS SQL Management studio 2008.
2. I installed ODBC driver
3. I installed SQLSRV version 53_ts_vc9 (from phpinfo() (vession - 5.3,
   thread safe, compiler - MSVC9))
4. I've added **extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll** line to php.ini
5. I've rebooted server and got **"--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"**
   in phpInfo()

Help me, guys. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Might be better suited for serverfault or superuser?

Answer (score 0):

> I've rebooted server and got "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"
>   in phpInfo()

Those are compile time options, not configuration options.  You need to compile php from source, or get a module that provides that functionality.

Comment: I thought tht *.dll provides functionality.